# How can I redict to same page after session expire in MVC project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
    //I Have a Action Method 
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(VmUser_User VmUser_User)
    {
        if (VmUser_User.User_User.UserName == null || 
        VmUser_User.User_User.Password == null)
        {
            VmUser_User.LblError = "Please enter Username and Password";
            return View(VmUser_User);
        }
        //Return valid user
        if (VmUser_User.LoginUser() > 0)
        {

            Session["One"] = VmUser_User;
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

        }
        else
        {
            VmUser_User.LblError = "User/Password does not match!";
        }

        return View(VmUser_User);
    }

   //And another Action Method
    public async Task<ActionResult> Common_Unit()
    {
        Oss.Romo.ViewModels.User.VmUser_User user = 
        (Oss.Romo.ViewModels.User.VmUser_User)Session["One"];
        if (user == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");
        }
        vmCommon_Unit = new VmCommon_Unit();
        await Task.Run(() => vmCommon_Unit.InitialDataLoad());

        return View(vmCommon_Unit);
    }
```

When a valid user login application, it redirect to Home/Index page, then he request for Common/Common_Unit page. After expire the session and user relogin the application I want to redirect in last requested page like Common/Common_Unit, please someone help me to solve this problem.

My Question : When a authorized user browse a specific page then he inactive some time. In the min time session out occurred and user go to login page. After login I want to redirect user on this specific page. Sorry for my Bad English

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ReturnUrl` parameter, like this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(VmUser_User VmUser_User)
    {
        if (VmUser_User.User_User.UserName == null ||
        VmUser_User.User_User.Password == null)
        {
            VmUser_User.LblError = "Please enter Username and Password";
            return View(VmUser_User);
        }
        //Return valid user
        if (VmUser_User.LoginUser() > 0)
        {

            Session["One"] = VmUser_User;

            if (Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] != null & Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] != "")
            {
                Response.Redirect(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            VmUser_User.LblError = "User/Password does not match!";
        }

        return View(VmUser_User);
    }

    //And another Action Method
    public async Task<ActionResult> Common_Unit()
    {
        Oss.Romo.ViewModels.User.VmUser_User user =
        (Oss.Romo.ViewModels.User.VmUser_User)Session["One"];
        if (user == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home", new { ReturnUrl = "/Common/Common_Unit" });
        }
        vmCommon_Unit = new VmCommon_Unit();
        await Task.Run(() => vmCommon_Unit.InitialDataLoad());

        return View(vmCommon_Unit);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is not for me. 
My Question : When a authorized user browse a specific page then he inactive some time. In the min time session out occurred and user go to login page. After login I want to redirect user on this specific page. Sorry for my Bad English.

Comment: sorry for not being able to help you :(   hope some can help you

Comment: Welcome Eva Lai.